# KIE workbench integration with Java: mismatched input '<' expecting one of the following tokens: '[package, import, global, declare,..]'

Tags: drools, kie

I'm trying to integrate drools kie workbench with java application. I'm Using jboss-as-7.1.1.Final as my workbench. Here is the rule definition:

```
package com.sample;
rule "set isEligible"
ruleflow-group "sample"
lock-on-active true
when
$p : Student(gpa > 2.0)
then
System.out.println("GPA is greater than 2..");
$p.setEligible(true);
end
```

From the java application i'm passing the student POJO object to the kieSession object and firing up the rules.
Here is the code:

```
    Student s = new Student();
    s.setName("Virat");
    s.setGpa(5.0f);
    URL u = new URL("http://localhost:8080/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-jboss-as7/kie-wb.html#%5Bnull%5D?path_uri=default://master@com/sample/src/main/resources/com/sample/sampleDRL.drl&file_name=sampleDRL.drl&has_version_support=true");
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
     kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newUrlResource(u), ResourceType.DRL );
     kbuilder.hasErrors();
     if (kbuilder.hasErrors() ) {
         System.out.println( kbuilder.getErrors() );
     }

    kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages();
    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
    KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();

    kieSession.insert(s);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

I'm able to connect to the workbench repository (com:sample:1.0) from the java app. But the problem is, i'm getting the following exception while executing the rule:

```
[8,0]: [ERR 107] Line 8:0 mismatched input '<' expecting one of the following tokens: '[package, import, global, declare, function, rule, query]'.
[0,0]: Parser returned a null Package
```

I don't know where i went wrong (because no where i have used '<' symbol).

Ask me for any missing detail. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to see the drl file in browser using above link? The link is probably returning you an html file, probably because of missing authentication or something.

Comment: Isn't there a stack trace?

Comment: @NavedAlam and laune, Thnks for the reply. I'm not sure it's the right way to access the workbench. Please suggest me how can i execute rules of workbench  from my java app.

Comment: @Raghu You can go through [this](http://blog.athico.com/2013/12/deployment-with-drools-60.html) to understand on how to access workbench through Java. Also, a lot of tutorial and SO questions are available covering the same topic

Comment: Ya, I went through  it. They have shown how to connect to the kie workbench repository, but not executing any rules from there. And that's where i'm stuck. Can you give me any link for accomplishing it?

Comment: @Raghu When you connect to repository all the rules in that repository are fired when you call fireAllRule. You should be really going through Drools documentation.

Comment: @NavedAlam how can i make it consider the POJO object from the java application and apply the rule on it in the workbench?

Comment: @Raghu Create a jar of your POJO class and upload it to the workbench repository. You can upload by going to Artifact Repository -> Upload. Then you can import your classes in your rules.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. I request you to answer two small questions: 1. How to delete a repository uploaded to the artifact repo? (since I've uploaded multiple versions of same repo) 2. Though I'm able to print a message based on a condition, I can't access the setter and getter methods of the POJO class. what could be the reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it mapping the word 'greater' to '<' ? in System.out.println